# Getting ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED when running .NET API on localhost from Visual Studio

Tags: .net, visual-studio, iis, localhost, iis-express

I'm a newbie in .NET coding, I'm trying to run a project using .NET using IIS Express on Google chrome, I get this error : ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED

[image]

Here is what I've tried so far, and it does not work:

- Changing the port number under properties section, and creating a new virtual directory
  [image]
- Removing the applicationhost.config from the .vs project folder
- Disabling the proxy
- Running Visual Studio as an Administrator
- Disabling the Script Debugging

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In my case, this issue was resolved by removing the `.vs` file followed by restarting Visual Studio as an Administrator

Answer (score 1):

While creating the database connection try to use port number with localhost it worked for me so might go same with you as well....
Good luck.

Answer (score 1):

Please try to visit your HTTPS address, some websites may disable HTTP connection, such as Asp.Net Core Application.
[image]
Besides, try to repair the IIS Express in the console panel.
[image]
Feel free to let me know if the problem still exists.

Answer (score 1):

1: control panel > programs and features > IIS express > repair
2: reboot the machine

Answer (score 0):

In case anyone else encounters this issue, I had a .net core app running react  and it worked fine for months. I then created a separate, unrelated Node.js and React app and the .net project stopped working and started throwing the error mentioned here.

What happened was I updated NPM and Node.js on my local for my new Node app, which wasn't compatible with my older .net app. I'm on a Mac, so to fix I used n from my console to switch back to the old Node version when running my .net app and it worked perfectly. Regarding the newer NPM, it worked with the older app, so I didn't have to reinstall an older version of NPM.